# When compiling using -std=c99 do I need to use -pedantic or -ansi?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I'm C/GCC noob, sorry. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, you also need to stand on 1 leg. Please if you ask this kind of question, at least read the man pages and explain why you think you need these options or not, and make your question specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `-ansi` is equivalent to using `-std=c89` or `-std=c++98` depending on whether you're compiling a C or C++ file, so you would not want to use it along with `-std=c99` as it would conflict.  `-pedantic` on the other hand is independent of `-std` so can be used along with it.

Answer (score 1):

The thing with -pedantic is that the clue is in the name; does anyone *need* to be pedantic?

If you *need* that level of compliance, then yes you need it, but resolving any of pedantic warnings is unlikely to affect the behaviour of your code, but rather just make more work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use -pedantic with either -std=c99 or -ansi.
-ansi and -std=c99 both are standard to be followed by compiler and conflict each other as only one standard can be follow at a time.

-padantic check the program with strict `ISO C` and `ISO C++` standard and reject any forbidden expression . without this option some traditional C and C++ feature can be allowed.